# Does anyone play Multiplayer? How much time would I need to commit?

Tags: civilization-5

I've been into the "Internet Games" screen several times but rarely see any games. I've been reluctant to join one because I don't know how it works.

Can anyone tell me:

- Is the list of "internet games" global?
- Why are there so few of them?
- How would the game work (I saw somewhere else it's RTS style)?
- How long will the game take to complete?
- Can I take a bathroom break without abandoning my civ temporarily?
- Can I chat to the other players?

It would be interesting to play against other people as I'm sure their strategies are way more creative and devious. But (how) does it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't answer the first two questions in a definitive manner.  However the rest I can handle:

**How would the game work (i saw somewhere else it's RTS style)?**

It's not quite RTS, but it's not turn-based either: every human player takes their turn at the same time.  Once all players click "next turn", the AI civilizations, city states and barbarians all take their turns in order.  Then the human players' next turn begins.

This causes some big issues when interacting with other players, and is a big griping point for many.  For example, wars became a battle of who can click first - if I can blow up your unit before they get a chance to attack, then I'm in a hugely advantage position.  It's unfortunate to the point where a lot of us don't even both with multiplayer (except cooperatively with friends) because when everyone moves at the same time, the game loses a lot of the carefully planned strategy you get in single player.

It's worth noting that once you click "next turn", you can't do anything even if other players are still moving - so it's to your advantage to delay the end of your turn a bit in case something comes up.

**How long will the game take to complete?**

Depends highly on the number of players and the game speed, but significantly longer than a single player game of the same settings.  Some turns you may be blazing through waiting for construction while another person is taking his sweet time waging war, and vice versa.  Even playing on quick/small map can take hours.  Set aside a large chunk of time.

**Can I take a bathroom break without abandoning my civ temporarily?**

Yes, you can just sit on the "next turn" button and not click it while you do something else.  You would just hold up everyone else from getting to the next turn.

**Can I chat to the other players?**

Yes.  There is a chat box that appears in the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: Are there no choices for consecutive turns?  The only option is simultaneous turns?

Comment: Correct.  There is no choice for consecutive turns at all and it really blows.  You could do a gentleman's agreement but even then it wouldn't be quite the same because of the timing of production/repair/etc.

Comment: And consecutive turns would take even longer.

Comment: Sounds like nothing has changed since I last gave up on multiplayer in Civ 2 or 3, for exactly the reasons you stated above. It really wouldn't be so hard to record all movements that lead to combat, then resolve them at the end of the turn (as many other round-based strategy games have done).

Answer (score 1):

The Internet games shown to you are not global, but are connected to the steam download server you default to (essentially your regional settings).

As for the number of games, this may be down to the playability of Multiplayer CIV5. Multiplayer seems to have been neglected, and games are very slow/buggy - especially in the later stages of the game when there are a lot of units/moves/cities.